# How to Install libprotobuf-c.so.1?

Tags: apt

A binary on my machine requires libprotobuf-c.so.1. I know that this is the Google Protocol Buffer library. How do I install this specific version though?

I searched for this library on: packages.ubuntu.com however [could not find it there](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libprotobuf-c.so.1).

I tried the following commands to install this library on Ubuntu 14.04 however the package was not found:

```
sudo apt install libprotobuf-c
sudo apt install libprotobuf-c1
```

Answer (score 1):

`libprotobuf-c.so.1` is provided by the [*libprotobuf-c1*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libprotobuf-c1/filelist) package in Ubuntu 18.04.

Open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/protobuf-c/libprotobuf-c1_1.2.1-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libprotobuf-c1_1.2.1-2_amd64.deb
```

If your Ubuntu 14.04 is 32-bit architecture you need to download protobuf-c/libprotobuf-c1_1.2.1-2_i386.deb instead.